# Run VSCode JS debug launch configuration from integrated terminal

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Currently when there's a need to debug a JS one could create a debug configuration, go to debug tab and hit play on the chose launch configuration. Is it possible to do that from an integrated terminal? e.g. `code --debug launchConfigurationName` or something?

Edit:

Found a discussion on the topic on GH - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10979. Nothing there that'd help unfortunately.

Comment: You could do start a debug config from a keybinding if that helps, see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config&ssr=false#overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this vscode extension: [Debug Launcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-debug-launcher)

Easy as running the following command in the terminal:

```sh
open 'vscode://fabiospampinato.vscode-debug-launcher/launch?args={"type":"node","name":"Foo","request":"launch","program":"/path/to/foo.js"}'
```